# vue.js and external jquery library

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have project on Laravel with Vue js 2. 
I created component Card.vue where i want to use jquery file upload plugin-
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

for that i need connect 3 js files

```
<script src="/js/file_upload/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/js/file_upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/js/file_upload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

I try to connect this files in footer of main page, in component but it doesn't work. 
Could you please help me - how can i connect external jquery libs with vue js components? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use npm modules to in order to load jquery plugins for such cases.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-file-upload.
If you have a webpack setup then you can load jquery through `ProvidePlugins`
npm install jquery then place this in your webpack config

`plugins:[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery:'jquery',
      jquery:'jquery'
    }),
  ],`

I don't know the setup for browserify but the idea here is to use these plugins via npm because it's more reliable. I had a similar situation with jquery fullcalendar and managed to get it work by installing the appropriate npm libraries.

Btw can you specify the errors you got or at least more details?